# Immutable Strings Python? Time complexity when indexing?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to solve a programming question.

```
Given a text string and words (a list of strings), return all index pairs [i, j] so that the substring text[i]...text[j] is in the list of words. 

Example 1:

Input: text = "thestoryofleetcodeandme", words = ["story","fleet","leetcode"]
Output: [[3,7],[9,13],[10,17]]
Example 2:

Input: text = "ababa", words = ["aba","ab"]
Output: [[0,1],[0,2],[2,3],[2,4]]
Explanation: 
Notice that matches can overlap, see "aba" is found in [0,2] and [2,4].
```

My function is

```
def indexPairs(text: str, words: List[str]) -> List[List[int]]:
    words = set(words) # O(w)
    text = list(text) # O(n)
    ans = []
    for l in range(len(text)): # O(n)
        for r in range(l + 1, len(text) + 1): # O(n)
            w = "".join(text[l:r])
            if w in words:
                ans.append((l, r - 1))
    return ans
```

My understanding is that this code runs in O(n^2) time complexity.

However, I'm confused about the 7th line, where I write `w = "".join(text[l:r])`. Would this be considered an O(n) operation as indexing the array (O(1) operation) and then copying it to a string (O(n) operation)?

So, is this code actually O(n^3)?

Thanks a lot for any guidance.

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry my understanding is that doing something like `list[4]` or `list[4:10]` is an `O(1)` operation?

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's me that misread, apologies

Comment: @SomyaAgrawal no, slicing is not constant time, it depends on the size of the slice. Note, there are no arrays here, so there's no indexing an array. Rather, you are taking the slice of a `str` object, which returns a *new `str` object*, of the size `r - l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the similarity in syntax, `text[l:r]` is a slicing operation, not an indexing operation. Indexing is O(1) because you lookup and return *one* of the *n* items. Here, though, the slice returns O(n) of the *n* items, so this is an O(n) operation, resulting in an O(n**3) running time for the function as a whole.

Comment: Technically O(n^3 + m) where m is the size of `words`, which is independent of the string length.